# XCode 4 freezes while archiving

Tags: xcode4, archive, freeze

I'm a relatively new IOS developer, having just started the beginning of this year.  I have finished the latest update to my app using XCode 4, but I cannot archive it.  It freezes with the status bar stating 4 out of 250 files compile, and I have to do a force quit. Can anyone tell me how I can figure out why the compilation hangs?

I've tried using both distribution and release settings.  I've tried changing compilers.  I've tried comparing the settings with those I have in XCode 3.  I've tried banging my head against the wall.  Nothing helps.